# Javascript to disable asp.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use the following Javascript to disable a button after click:

```
var c = 0;
function DisableClick(target) {
    var objName = target;
    document.getElementById(objName).disabled = true;
    c = c + 1;
    msg = 'Please Wait...(' + c + ')!';
    document.getElementById(objName).value = msg;
    var t = setTimeout('DisableClick()', 1000);
}

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="cssLoginButton blue"  Text="Log in" ToolTip="Log in" ValidationGroup="UserLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="DisableClick('btnLogin')" />
```

My Javascript gives this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'disabled': object is null or undefined

[image: Error Given by script]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the clicked button object in javascript function. Return false if you do not need postback.

Change

```
OnClientClick="DisableClick('btnLogin')"
```

To

```
// the DisableClick make a loop, so make the return here.
OnClientClick="DisableClick(this);return false;" 


function DisableClick(target) {   
    target.disabled = true;
    c = c + 1;
    msg = 'Please Wait...(' + c + ')!';
    target.value = msg;

    // The DisableClick needs the target parametre, so send it again
    //  but need to keep it here for work.
    var me = target;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){DisableClick(me);}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: and also must return false, or else is doing post back.

Comment: Thanks @Aristos i get this error **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined**

Comment: You need to change  document.getElementById(objName).value = msg; to  target.value = msg;

Comment: @Aristos & Adil yes I disable it for 1 sec. because I mentioned time in my script but after 1 sec I get same error **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'disabled': object is null or undefined**

Comment: @Ajay When is run the `SetTimeOut`, Adil here forget to give it an argument again, so its not find it.

Comment: Problem solve thanks @Aristos and Adil 
I just change setTimeout(function(){DisableClick(**me**);}, 1000);
to setTimeout(function(){DisableClick(**this**);}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
OnClientClick = "JavaScript: return false; "
```

also

```
document.getElementbyid (objectName)
```

returns null

are you sure you're passing the correct id of the. button?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is call the function on load of the body and it should work fine. So the code will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableBtn()
{
var btn= document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID%>");
btn.disabled=true;
}
</script>
```

Html

```
<body onload="javascript:disableBtn();">

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 ...
 </body>
```

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** This should solve your solution of Disabling the button as well as displaying a message until the process has finished

**Markup**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

      .... Your other code

        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="cssLoginButton blue"  Text="Log in" ToolTip="Log in"
           OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" ValidationGroup="UserLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click"  />

     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Please Wait...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

To test it

**Code behind**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Introducing delay for demonstration.
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);      
}
```